# IApp purchase doubts in iphone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Ha ii,everybody.I have a reader application which has a database downloading option through inapp,that is,the user can download the diffrent languages of databse(Sqlite) through inapp.I i added the classes from [MugunthKumar classes](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit) and added it into the project.I have 5 buttons hindiDB,HebrewDB,japaneseDB,portuguesDB etc,etc.If the user tap any of the button above it will automatically connect to in-app and if the payment done ,it need to download that DB to my app.I write this code in one of my button click:

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnhindilang:(id)sender
{
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:kFeatureAId 
                                onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature)
 {
     NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature);
 }
                               onCancelled:^
 {
     NSLog(@"User Cancelled Transaction");
 }];
}
```

and the console shows that it cannot built in ios stumulator and ned to build in realdevise,so i build it with a real devise and the console shows

```
Review request cannot be checked now: (null)
2011-12-06 14:39:33.958 Bible[965:707] User cancelled transaction: <SKPaymentTransaction: 0x373110>
2011-12-06 14:39:33.961 Bible[965:707] error: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x3dc4d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

I didnt know how to do a inapp purchase.How can done this with MukunthKumar storekit class.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what did do you do up to now? have you enabled your app for In App Purchase? did you add items to iTunes connect?

Comment: @shannoga sir ,i think i really need your help.I already done adding classes from MukunthKumar Github,and [MKStoreManager sharedManager];in appDidFinishLaunch,and in button click i done what i mentioned above in question

Comment: @shannoga i have my DB with me,How can i add it to the itunes sir?and sir ,how can i enable my app for inapp purchase.but my app have the provising certificate

Comment: I am sorry but it is way over this platform to explain all the steps. I will look for a good tutorial for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

And slow down a little bit, your rush will prevent you from learning.

Shani